# Firing objectWillChange for an array in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, observableobject

I understand how a swift `ObservableObject` isn't seen as changed/updated when an array element (class) is changed. I have added a listener to the array items which works, however I can't fire off an `objectWillChange` for the array because an array doesn't have the `objectWillChange` function.

I have a global singleton like this:

```
final class GlobalData: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = GlobalData()
    
    var cancellables = [AnyCancellable]()
    @Published private(set) var lists: [List] = [] {
        didSet {
            lists.forEach({ [unowned self] list in
                let c = list.objectWillChange.sink { _ in
                    self.objectWillChange.send()
                }
                self.cancellables.append(c)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I want to monitor changes in `SwiftUI` of the array like this:

```
.onChange(of: globalData.lists) { _ in
    print("✅", "lists changed")
}
```

The problem is, as it's a singleton I don't want to trigger the `objectWillChange` on `self` as it always remains the same, I need to trigger it on the published array.

Although the `Array` is `@Published` I cannot fire off `lists.objectWillChange.send()` as I get the error:

```
Value of type '[WishList]' has no member 'objectWillChange'
```

So I guess my question is, how can an `Array` be happy with `@Published` if I cannot trigger it?

Can I add this function to the Array, or is there another way to trigger the publisher?

There is a slight workaround, but it's not great...

I can add a new published property:

```
@Published private(set) var listsChanged = UUID()
```

Then in my array listener I change the `UUID`. Now in SwiftUI if I watch `listsChanged` for changes, I get the callbacks I need. But there must be a way to get them from the array?

EDIT -------

Here's an example of my view:

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var globalData: GlobalData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {}
        .onChange(of: globalData.lists) { _ in
            print("✅", "lists changed")
        }
    }
}
```

I get the lists changed call when I initially set the array, but not if I fire off `self. objectWillChange.send()` on the `GlobalData` object.

Comment: `objectWillChange` gets fired on an `ObservableObject` any time any `@Published` property changes. So, your worry that you're firing it on `self` rather than the array doesn't make a lot of sense. Your SwiftUI view will update whenever any property changes on the `ObservableObject`. That being said, I highly recommend changing your model to a `struct`, as that's what SwiftUI (up until the version that's in beta right now) is really built for.

Comment: `struct` is out of the question. I've gone back and forward from struct to class to struct to class. I just can't make it work as struct as the object itself downloads extra data and images that belong to it.

Comment: Anyway, I get the `objectWillChange` notification when I initially set the array, but when the array items make their own updates I want the array listener to fire as if it changed again. As the actual array doesn't change, the listener isn't triggered, so how can I manually trigger it?

Comment: I've added an edit with my view code.

Comment: You can't use `onChange` with a non-Equatable type like this. `onChange` doesn't respond to `objectWillChange`.

Comment: Ok so onChange not responding to objectWillChange makes what I’m seeing make sense. Is there a way to make onChange respond to an array element change?

Answer (score 0):

I really think you are trying to abuse the `@Published` and `ObservableObject` mechanism.

That scheme is for an object to report its *own* changes to another object, and it's specifically targeted at making it easy for Swift UI views observing their own state.  It's not really meant as a general implementation of the Observer pattern.

From a logical standpoint, using `@Published` and `ObservableObject` for `GlobalData` is incorrect because it's not the `GlobalData` that's changing.  It's trying to report that something it owns is changing, and that's a logically distinct (albeit related) message.

Another use of the Observable pattern may be more appropriate to report that event.

For example, a delegate pattern:

```
protocol GlobalDataDelegate {
  func listsChanged()
}

class List: ObservableObject {
}

class GlobalData {
  var delegate: (any GlobalDataDelegate)?

  var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

  var lists: [List] = [] {
    didSet {
        cancellables = lists.map { [weak self] in
          $0.objectWillChange.sink { self?.delegate?.listsChanged() }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Or if want to use Combine:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class List: ObservableObject {
}

enum GlobalDataEvent {
  case listsChanged(List)
}

class GlobalData {
  let listsChanged: AnyPublisher<GlobalDataEvent, Never>
  private let listsChangedSubject = PassthroughSubject<GlobalDataEvent, Never>()

  var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []
  var lists: [List] = [] {
    didSet {
        cancellables = lists.map { [weak self] list in
          list.objectWillChange.sink { self?.listsChangedSubject.send(.listsChanged(list)) }
        }
    }
  }

  init() {
    listsChanged = listsChangedSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

In either of these two examples the logical event that is happening is clearly defined, more precisely than simply "object changed". In the observer case what's being reported is clear from the context of which delegate method was called.  In the Combine case, the event has a distinct enum case that makes the notification explicit.  Either should be more readable and understandable in your code.

In the delegate case your view will have to set itself as the delegate and implement the delegate protocol. In the Combine case your view can use `onReceive` view modifier to watch the `listsChanged` publisher.

(You could also use `NSNotificationCenter` with a distinct notification name to get the same effect).

However you solve your problem, I believe `ObservableObject` and `@Published` are the wrong implementation of the Observer pattern to use here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are trying to reimplement SwiftUI's change tracking which is a waste of time IMO.

Just make a `View` struct and pass in the object's properties that you want to display. `body` will be called when any of the properties change. If you want to transform a property use a computed property into the View init so the result can be change tracked.

Use `.task` or `.task(id: aProperty)` to download your extra data.

Then simply call objectWillChange.send() when you load or save the array of objects in your store object and SwiftUIs change tracking/diffing will take care of the rest. Make sure you are observing the store object in the View that has the ForEach.